# How to replace <br/> tag with the \n(new line) in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp-tags

I use this code snippets to replace `<br/>` tag with the "\n"(new line) in jquery. But it did not work

```
  $("#UserTextArea").html(data.projectDescription).replace(/\<br\>/g, "\n");
```

But it did not work why is that?

Answer (score 2):

`.replace()` does not change the contents itself.  It returns a new string so if you want to use that new string, you have to put the return value from `.replace()` somewhere.

You may also need to fix your regex if you're targeting `<br\>` by escaping the \ and making it optional.

FYI, in HTML a `\n` doesn't do anything so if you're just trying to remove all `<br>` tags in `#UserTextArea`, you can just use the DOM parser to do this:

```
$("#UserTextArea br").remove();
```

Or, if you just want to get the string with `<br>` tags replaced into a variable that you can use for something else, you can do this:

```
var str = $("#UserTextArea").html().replace(/\<br\\?>/g, "\n");
```

Or, you're string to remove `<br>` form `data.projectDescription` and assign it as he HTML to `#UserTextArea`, you can do this:

```
$("#UserTextArea").html(data.projectDescription..replace(/\<br\\?>/g, "\n"));
```

Comment: I think a newline does mean something within the pre tag?

Answer (score 1):

`$("#UserTextArea").html(data.projectDescription.replace(/\<br[\/]*\>/g, "\n"));`

Comment: Its not working mate. Also i use  $("#UserTextArea").html(data.projectDescription.replace("<br/>", "\n")); it also not working

Comment: What is the content of `data.projectDescription`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#UserTextArea').html(data.projectDescription.replace(/\<br\s*\>/g, '\n'));
```

Or, to search and replace the inner HTML of an element:

```
var $element = $('#UserTextArea');
var html = $element.html();
$element.html(html.replace(/\<br\s*\>/g, '\n'));
```